Getting ClassNotFoundException for "com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory" after migrating from Tomcat 9.0.87 to 9.0.88
I've recently migrated my Struts web project from Tomcat version 9.0.87 to 9.0.88. When I start the
Tomcat I'm not able to access the site and seeing blank pages. And found the below error in the log
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.compiler.EncodingDetector
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.determineSyntaxAndEncoding(ParserController.java:324) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:201) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:128) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:203) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:392) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:368) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:352) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
74 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory not found [in thread "http-nio-8080-exec-2"]
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:184) ~[?:?]
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:135) ~[?:?]
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:248) ~[?:?]
    at javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:210) ~[?:?]
    at javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newFactory(XMLInputFactory.java:185) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.EncodingDetector.<clinit>(EncodingDetector.java:41) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.determineSyntaxAndEncoding(ParserController.java:324) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:201) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:128) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:203) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:392) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:368) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:352) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327) ~[jasper.jar:9.0.89]
74 more


when I checked the changelog for Tomcat 9.0.88, I've found this line under Jasper section:

Prevent the web application's ClassLoader from being pinned by the JSP compiler if an application uses a custom XMLInputFactory. Based upon a suggestion from Simon Niederberger. (schultz)

I've placed the jar files containing the com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory in the lib folder of Tomcat and it worked. I am able to access all the pages in my application.
But I don't want to make changes to the Tomcat itself but want to fix the issue by making changes to my project only.

In your case XMLInputFactory is pinned from the Common classloader. You can read more about Tomcat's classloader How-To. Since you can't change the location of Jasper compiler, or just provide the Jasper embedded artifact. The classpath is searched from the property file for additional classes. These classes you need to add  to the common classloader's classpath.
